# IAM Cloudformation template best practise?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm wondering if it makes more sense to put all IAM roles and policies into one template in a nested stack to keep them easier maintainable or if good practise is saying thats rather detrimental for whatever reason and to put the policies to the specific templates where the resources are created. Which way is better. for the sake of good order i would go with the ONE template cause the idea seems alright. I would be grateful for shared experiences in this matter.

Merci A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have recently templatized the whole AWS infrastructure using cloudformation. And, I would keep the IAM roles and policies closer to the application stack rather than in one template. I will try to explain my reasons.

We have a separate AWS account for every TeamEnv.

```
What is a TeamEnv?
```

If we have 3 teams e.g. A, B, and C. 
And 3 environments e.g. Dev, Staging, and Prod.

Then we have 9 TeamEnv: A-Dev, A-Staging, A-Prod and so on for every other teams. So, in total, we have 9 AWS accounts. This is done to set accountability as well as transparency of resources.

And, here's how we did it. We divided the stacks into these categories:

- Common AWS Cloudformation Stacks
- TeamEnv Specific AWS Cloudformation Stacks

**Common AWS Cloudformation Stacks:**
These are the stacks that would be common for all teams and their environments:

- *IAM Sub User Account Stack* - This stack creates an IAM Sub Account with Administrator access rights.
- *Generic VPC Stack* - This stack creates the VPC and its components as per the company's standards.
- *VPC Peering Stack* - This stack is to peer VPCs.
- *VPC Peering Role Stack* - This stack creates a VPC role required to peer.

**Team Specific Stacks:**

- *ELB Stack* - It is dependent on *Generic VPC* stack and imports the exported values from it, like *VPCId*.
- *Service Specific Stack* - It is dependent on *Generic VPC* stack and *ELB Stack* and imports various exported values.  We have one stack for every micro-service and it consists of everything that it needs to take the service to a ready state. It includes s3 buckets, SQS, InstanceRole, etc.

That's where we manage the IAM roles and policies. It's easier to manage and audit.

However, in hindsight, I would have kept a separate stack for IAM policies, which are commonly used and referenced in other roles, to avoid duplicated in-line policies.

Comment: merci, great insight, so I will at least develop one stack for the policies, any chance i could contact you directly for further questions?